# Nitro to Electric Conversion

Tags: esc, brushless-motors, motor, engine

Attempting to convert a ThunderTiger Ready MkIII nitro to electric.
Manufacturer recommended engines are:

*Thunder Tiger Aircraft Engine GP-42:
1.10 BHP @ 14,000 RPM,  357.2 g / 12.60 oz., 6.90 c.c. / .421 cu.in.*

and

*Thunder Tiger Aircraft Engine Pro 46:
1.60 BHP @ 16,000 RPM, 448.5 g / 15.82 oz. , 7.47 c.c. / .456 cu.in.*

What would be a reasonable, or a bit overpowered, equivalent electric motor and esc?